SAXParseException:'[word/document.xml line 2]: XML Declaration allowed only at the start of the document ' , Stream 'word/document.xml',Line 2

Here is the code . Want to take all content of one docx anf find a sting and replace with that.
Please help me , how to do this , Thanks in advance.
<?php    
$template_file_name = "bb.docx";
$source = "aa.docx";    
$rand_no = rand(111111, 999999);
$fileName = "results_" . $rand_no . ".docx";
$source_fileName = "results_" . rand(111111, 999999) . "sss" . ".docx";    
$folder = "results_";
$full_path = $folder . "/" . $fileName;
$source_full_path = $folder . "/" . $source_fileName;    
if (!file_exists($folder)) {
    mkdir($folder);
}    
//Copy the Template file to the Result Directory
copy($template_file_name, $full_path);
copy($source, $source_full_path);    
// add calss Zip Archive
$zip_val = new ZipArchive();
$source_zip_val = new ZipArchive();    
//Docx file is nothing but a zip file. Open this Zip File
if ($zip_val->open($full_path) == true) {
    $key_file_name = "word/document.xml";
    // In the Open XML Wordprocessing format content is stored.
    // In the document.xml file located in the word directory.
    if ($source_zip_val->open($source)) {
        $source_message = $source_zip_val->getFromName($key_file_name);
        var_dump($source_message);
    }    
    $message = $zip_val->getFromName($key_file_name);
    $message = str_replace("#Content Starts Here#", $source_message, $message);
    //Replace the content with the new content created above.
    sleep(2);
    $zip_val->addFromString($key_file_name, $message);
    $zip_val->close();    
    sleep(2);
    $source_zip_val->addFromString($key_file_name, $source_message);
    $source_zip_val->close();    
    echo "PROCESS DONE";
}   
?>

Please help me with proper guidance.

Which line of this code is throwing the exception? It's unclear. You provided neither a stack trace nor any line numbers. Provide proper details of the exception in the question body, not just a summary in the title. See also [ask]

This exception showing when I try to open the docx file

Ah ok. So basically your code has corrupted the file. Have you checked the raw content of the generated docx files using a zip file tool? It looks like you're trying to manipulate an XML file using naive string replacement. It would make more sense to use an XML library, or even better perhaps a docx library

Not find open source good library for that.

https://www.google.com/search?q=php+docx reveals several. Have you investigated them all? Do none of them meet your needs? Why not? And that's just the docx ones... there are plenty of XML ones too, as a fallback option. It would be quite surprising if none of them could do accurate text replacement within a specific element of the document.

phpdox I checked , it will work for me , But it is not free , it is paid ,Anyway I will try to do with ZipArchive ,
Thanks

Have you tried phpword? That one is open source

phpword  itself using ZipArchive , :)

Yes...but it does more. It provides a cleaner interface to the structure of a docx document than just treating it like a raw zip file. You're more likely to be able to replace text in a section of the document without corrupting the file, if you use a tool like that which is built around the specific docx specification, not just the basic zip specification

You're inserting a full XML file string ($source_message = $source_zip_val->getFromName($key_file_name);) with an XML declaration into another XML file $message = str_replace("#Content Starts Here#", $source_message, $message);. This will break any XML file.
